# C# WPF set DataGrid to non-editable mode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The problem is when I do right mouse click on the grid it crush the application

```
DataGrid x:Name="dgDbList" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" 
EnableRowVirtualization="False"/>

using (SqlCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myCommand.CommandText = sqlCmd; // here select statement like : select 1 as a, 2 as b union all select 3, 5

    SqlDataReader SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    SqlDataReader.Close();

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    grid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

    grid.CanUserAddRows = false;
    grid.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
    grid.CanUserResizeColumns = false;
    grid.CanUserResizeRows = false;
    grid.CanUserSortColumns = false;
    grid.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
    grid.IsReadOnly = true;

    foreach ( var col in grid.Columns )
    {
        col.IsReadOnly = true;
        col.CanUserReorder = false;
        col.CanUserResize = false;
        col.CanUserSort = false;
    }
}
```

> Exception: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled Message: An
>   unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll Additional information: Value cannot be
>   null.

Comment: i don't think you've covered the essentias in the code you posted. you mention a nullpointer exception on right-click, but i see nothing in the code related to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.IsReadOnly = true;
```

Should be enough.

This is just an assumption because you haven't posted the full stacktrace. I belie you get the exception because you try to iterate over autogenerating columns.  I suggest you use the **AutoGeneratingColumn** event instead.

Example:

```
grid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
    e.Column.CanUserReorder = false;
    e.Column.CanUserResize = false;
    e.Column.CanUserSort = false;
};
```

Comment: Im not doing anything - grid just display the result of non-editable sql statement.  
QA want's do right click and application is crushing immediately.
I have no more stack trace then text of exception.

Comment: @ConstChumak if it already display the result then there is nothing wrong with the code you posted. the problem is somewhere else...  if you can reproduce the problem in a small project, feel free to post a download link here and I will try to see if I can help with something